# Как упростить ввод задачи на C#?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Имею такой код:

```
using System;

namespace YaContest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] game1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(':');
            string[] game2 = Console.ReadLine().Split(':');
            if (game1 == null || game2 == null) Console.WriteLine(-1);
            int g11 = int.Parse(game1[0]);
            int g12 = int.Parse(game1[1]);
            int g21 = int.Parse(game2[0]);
            int g22 = int.Parse(game2[1]);
            int game = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (game == 1){
                int score1 = g11 * 100 + g21 * 101;
                int score2 = g12 * 101 + g22 * 100;
                Console.WriteLine(Math.Max(0, score2 - score1 + 101) / 101);
            } else
            {
                int score1 = g11 * 101 + g21 * 100;
                int score2 = g12 * 100 + g22 * 101;
                Console.WriteLine(Math.Max(0, score2 - score1 + 100) / 100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно упростить ввод из консоли? На входе 3 строки, первая и вторая представляют футбольный счёт в виде "x:x", третья строка целое число.

Comment: Код очень подозрительный. Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Что вам тут не нравиться и что вы хотите поменять? Пока я вижу мешанину из всего, которую стоит разбить на классы, свойства, методы, тогда уже можно будет сделать к примеру такой вид `var game = Game.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`, а далее уже использовать конкретные свойства, например `game.Team[0].Score;` (или если это не нужно и команд всегда 2, то `game.FirstScore`), ну и так далее... Как видите, все объектно и все на своем месте получается. Ну а ввод, как по мне `:` - это сложный знак, проще через запятую или пробел (привычней многим), но кто знает, может вы просто копируете эти значения...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вы не любите футбол, а равно как и многие другие виды спорта? Счёт в матче традиционно разделяется двоеточием, и это и есть знак, привычный многим. Фанаты могут обидеться :-)

Comment: А вот запятая для разделения чисел - это действительно сложный знак.

Comment: @rotabor При чем тут футбол и другие виды спорта? Это самый базовый и банальный UX. Если программа просит от вас скажем **ввести** 10 параметров сразу, то как обычно она просит такое? Правильно, через запятую или пробел, условно "Введите все значения разделенные пробелом", это уже как по мне, стандарт, удобный и понятный всем. После ввода **отображение** уже может быть каким угодно, но ввод, извините... А вот двоеточие, это очень специфичный знак для ввода, и очень редко он используется, да и в основном используется в файлах для разделения, но не для ручного ввода пользователем.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ UX - это думать, как пользователь. Как он напишет счёт в матче? Традиционно 1:0 (в мою пользу). "10 параметров сразу" - это другая задача, и у вас будет возможность специфицировать ввод пользователя, если вам доверят делать постановку задачи.

Comment: @rotabor "Как он напишет счёт в матче?" - я вам написал выше. Считаете иначе, ваше право. На этом все.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное, что тут можно упростить со вводом:

```
string[] game1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(':');
string[] game2 = Console.ReadLine().Split(':');
if (game1 == null || game2 == null) Console.WriteLine(-1);
int g11 = int.Parse(game1[0]);
int g12 = int.Parse(game1[1]);
int g21 = int.Parse(game2[0]);
int g22 = int.Parse(game2[1]);

-->

int[] game1 = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(':'), int.Parse);
int[] game2 = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(':'), int.Parse);
```

Обработку ошибок добавить по необходимости.

P. S. Ну, и третью строку нет необходимости преобразовывать в число:

```
int game = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (game == 1){

-->

if (Console.ReadLine().Trim() == "1"){
```